# Confusion whether all physical quantities can be considered as fields

Tags: field-theory

Feynman has defined field as any physical quantity that takes different values at different points in space. I am facing difficulties while trying to find out physical quantities that don't satisfy this definition and hence cant be considered as fields. Eg. Area. I cant really understand whether it satisfies this definition or not. Please help with this.

Comment: I think of you ask yourself the question "area $of what$?", you'll see that area is unlikely to be a field.

Answer (score 1):

The spatial integral of a field is not a field for instance. More concretely, if you consider the density of a cup its quite localized but is a field nevertheless. The mass of the cup on the other hand is not a field.